# What is the difference between $one and var one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, var

What is the difference between **$one** and **var one** in JavaScript? Because both works.

 
 
Example:

```
$one = 'hello word!';

var one = 'hello word!';
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rS9PR/

Comment: Putting $ in front of variables is the Hungarian notation for jQuery. Please don't do it.

Comment: one = 'hello word!'; //global scope ,

var one = 'hello word!'; //local scope

Answer (score 3):

Nothing special about $; just another variable name. The use of "var" tells the interpreter that the variable has a local scope. WIthout var => global. ie; accessed from anywhere within the page.

Answer (score 2):

`var one` guarantees that the variable is set to local scope.

By default `$one` will assign the variable to global scope.

Answer (score 0):

They're both variable names. In JavaScript the $ character is a valid character for a variable name. The var keyword just sets the scope on the variable names one in your example.

The $ has grown popular due to its use in different JavaScript libraries like jQuery, however it's a perfectly valid variable name character to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, a variable name may contain a `$` sign in it. You have just declared two different variables - `$one` and `one`.

upd: as per @yi_H comment- the two variables actually have different scopes. `var` keyword is used to declare a variable in current scope, however if you omit the `var`, it is defined in the global namespace

Answer (score 0):

$one is defined in the global scope and will be visible in every function. `var one` is defined in its enclosing scope and is not visible outside.

Answer (score 0):

Some people use "$" as a prefix to indicate jQuery object, like:

```
$text = $("#myTextElement");
```

Answer (score 0):

Both names are valid identifiers, no difference. For the use of the var keyword see [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The `$` in `$one` does not mean anything special. It is just another normal JavaScript variable. There is a convention among some developers where the prefix variables with `$` to indicate that the variable holds a jQuery object. This is purely for style and readability and does not have a technical or syntactical impact.

When you omit the `var` from a declaration, a browser will attach the variable to the global object:

```
foo = 'bar';
alert(window.foo); // 'bar'
```

This has some pretty significant implications for any site that has more than a trivial amount of JavaScript (a category that has been growing rapidly over the last few years). The best practice is to **always** declare your variables with `var` to prevent a number of problems later on down the road.

See: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) for more detail on variable scope.